# Why searchtimeline is not showing any tweets for my hashtag using fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to show tweets containing a `hashtag`(#helpplus) that I newly created for testing but as results it shows no tweets while I try to do it with any other `hashtag` it shows up.

Please suggest what should I do so that `hashtag` created by me comes in results.

my code is:

```
final SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
.query("#helpplus")
.build();
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(getActivity())
.setTimeline(searchTimeline)
.setViewStyle(R.style.tw__TweetLightWithActionsStyle)
.build();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I responded over on the Twitter developer forums, if a user ID or a hashtag is very new, they may not appear in the Search API results immediately because the search index is not complete and there are measures to keep low quality results from appearing. It is likely that your Tweets were not indexed at the time that you tried this code. As of now, there are a few results in the search API that match, so it should work.

Also note that there is a 7-day limit on the search index, so if you were searching for something that hadn't been Tweeted about within that period of time, then your timeline would be empty even though you may see results in a search on Twitter.com

Comment: Yeah you are right..I reached to the same conclusion, thanks for answer.